# Local file download is corrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to download a file to my windows pc using nodejs

I tried the following code. the problem is the file which i download from nodejs is 185kb and the actual original file size is 113kb(found by directly downloading from browser)

```
request = require('request');

function download(url, dest, cb){
  request.head(url, function(err, res, body){
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest)).on('close', function(){
        cb();
    });
  });
};
```

I also tried downloading the file using a different code

```
function download(url, dest, cb) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    var request = https.get(url, function (response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function () {
            file.close(cb);
            file.end();
        });
    });
}
```

But the same bug happened

The problem is i am trying to open that file in photoshop , but it fails , saying the file is corrupted, please help

Comment: First of all, open the downloaded file using a text- or hex-editor, and check what makes up those extra kilobytes of data it contains. Often in such cases it is either error messages that got output into the result, or parts of the general site template that where not correctly suppressed for this special kind of response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code (using the built-in https module) should work correctly. The stream will close automatically, there's no need to close it, the autoClose parameter defaults to true when creating a write file stream.

See docs at: [fs.createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options).

If the file is still too large it is likely that you are not using the direct image link, try selecting "View image" / "Open image in new tab" etc. in your browser and using that link instead.

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg/1024px-FullMoon2010.jpg";
const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream("test.jpg");
https.get(url, response => {
    response.pipe(fileStream);
});
```

You can also use the request library:

```
const request = require("request");
const fs = require("fs");

const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg/1024px-FullMoon2010.jpg";
const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream("request-test.jpg");
const req = request(url);

req.on("response",  response => {
    response.pipe(fileStream);
});
```

Comment: My mistake was i was trying to view a proxy file, while the original file was downloaded. Big facepalm moment, Thanks for the answer

Comment: Great to hear you go past the issue!